# Create Complex & Dynamic rowspan in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I try to make function that get an array of object and according to object in the array generate a table with dynamic rowspan.
I tried many solutions but none of them helped.

I tried this code,but I did not continue it because the beginning did not work well

```
 const returnTabel = state => {
return state.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      {Object.keys(item).map((key, index) => {
        if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
          return item[key].map((object, index) => {
            return Object.keys(object).map((i, index) => {
              if (Array.isArray(object[i])) {
              } else {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{object[i]}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          return (
            <td rowSpan={2} key={index}>
              {item[key]}
            </td>
          );
        }
      })}
    </tr>
  );
});};
```

Here is my data:

```
 const state = [
{
  name: 'Bill',
  info: [
    {
      hobby: 'Practice',
      field: [
        { type: 'Swim', hours: '6' },
        { type: 'Run', hours: '7' }
      ]
    },
    {
      hobby: 'Listen to music',
      field: [
        { type: 'Jazz', hours: '3' },
        { type: 'Electronic music', hours: '3' },
        { type: 'Hip hop', hours: '3' }
      ]
    }
  ],
  student: 'No'
},
{
  name: 'John',
  info: [
    {
      hobby: 'Practice',
      field: [
        { type: 'Swim', hours: '1' },
        { type: 'Run', hours: '2' }
      ]
    }
  ],
  student: 'Yes'
}]
```

I want to make this table with my data

[image]

Comment: `tried many solutions`.  Could you show us?

Comment: @Keith I added.But it does not really work ..

Comment: Best suggestion is treat this as an array mapping exercise outside of React. Then once you can map it in javascript alone pass it to the react render

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the render mapping if you map the data to rows that look like:

```
[{"txt":"Bill","rowSpan":5},{"txt":"Practice","rowSpan":2},{"txt":"Swim"},{"txt":"6"},{"txt":"No","rowSpan":5}]
//OR
[null,{"txt":"Listen to music","rowSpan":3},{"txt":"Jazz"},{"txt":"3"},null]
//OR
[null,null,{"txt":"Run"},{"txt":"7"},null]
```

Then the render simplifies down to:

```
  return (
    <table border="1">
      {rows.map(cells =>  (
          <tr>
            {cells.map(cell => cell && <td rowSpan={cell.rowSpan}>{cell.txt}</td>)}
          </tr>
        )
      )}
    </table>
  );
```

---

Working example

```js
const data=[{name:"Bill",info:[{hobby:"Practice",field:[{type:"Swim",hours:"6"},{type:"Run",hours:"7"}]},{hobby:"Listen to music",field:[{type:"Jazz",hours:"3"},{type:"Electronic music",hours:"3"},{type:"Hip hop",hours:"3"}]}],student:"No"},{name:"John",info:[{hobby:"Practice",field:[{type:"Swim",hours:"1"},{type:"Run",hours:"2"}]}],student:"Yes"}];

const rowData = data.reduce((a, { name, info, student }) => {
  const rowSpan = info.reduce((a, { field }) => a + field.length, 0);

  let [firstCell, lastCell] = [name, student].map(txt => ({ txt, rowSpan }));

  info.forEach(({ hobby, field }, i) => {
    const rowSpan = field.length;

    let hobCell = { txt: hobby, rowSpan };

    field.forEach((f, j) => {
      const fieldCells = Object.values(f).map(txt => ({ txt }));

      if (j > 0) {
        hobCell = firstCell = lastCell = null;
      }
      const row = [firstCell, hobCell, ...fieldCells, lastCell];
      a.push(row);
    });
  });

  return a;
}, []);

console.log( rowData)

const Table = () => {
  const [rows] = React.useState(rowData);

  return (
    <table border="1">
      {rows.map((cells,i) =>  (
          <tr key={i}>
            {cells.map((cell,j) => cell && <td key={`${i}-${j}`} rowSpan={cell.rowSpan}>{cell.txt}</td>)}
          </tr>
        )
      )}
    </table>
  );
};
// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Table />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: All the point that the information appears in the table together will be found as one object ..

Comment: I mean that all the information that appears in the table as a single row that splits into several rows should appear as an object in the array I receive

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. If you need to edit or something you can include indexing detail in the rows objects  that make it simple to use `find()` on the master data